# How can I access promoted results using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, csom

I am basically rolling my own search center using CSOM (because...I need the control to make this thing look decent!).  How do I use all the query rule stuff with CSOM?  There doesn't seem to be a property on the search result objects that denotes "promoted result" or anything.  Do I need to submit a separate query to get promoted results?

Comment: Hey! Did you get any success?